# Connection Reset on simple flask application

Tags: python, jquery, post, flask

I've the following python script.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('smart_writer.html')

@app.route('/check_grammer', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def check_grammer():
    return request.method


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

I created the following ajax request.

```
$('.check-grammer').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#exampleTextarea').val() === '') {
        alert('no text to convert');
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/check_grammer',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            text: $('#exampleTextarea').val()
        }, null, '\t'),
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    })
})
```

When i run the application and run the ajax, the chrome dev tools network panel says the following.

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

The python console says the following.

```
PS C:\Users\Imesh Chandrasiri\Desktop\grammer_checker> python .\grammer_checker.py
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 549-721-387
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 16:16:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 16:17:01] "POST /check_grammer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 16:17:01] "POST /check_grammer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 16:17:01] "POST /check_grammer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 16:17:01] "POST /check_grammer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2018 16:19:34] "POST /check_grammer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

What am I doing wrong here. I googled about this issue and couldn't figure it out. I'm new to python.

Comment: I am not sure but instead of return `request.method` return `'Method: %s' % request.method` from `check_grammer` function

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue - I see the console say "POST"